# Select attribute via XPath only if child element does not exist?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have a sample XML fragment that is like below

```
<asdiOutput xmlns="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS" xmlns:nxce="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/NasXCoreElements" 
    xmlns:mmd="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/MessageMetaData" 
    xmlns:nxcm="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/NasXCommonMessages" 
    xmlns:idr="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_IDRS" 
    xmlns:xis="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS http://localhost:58489/tfms/schema/TFMS_XIS.xsd" 
    timestamp="2011-03-15T23:57:59Z">
  <asdiMessage sourceFacility="CCZM" sourceTimeStamp="2011-03-15T23:57:27Z" trigger="TZ">
    <trackInformation>
      <nxcm:aircraftId>UAL966</nxcm:aircraftId>
      <nxcm:speed>470</nxcm:speed>
      <nxcm:reportedAltitude>
        <nxce:assignedAltitude>
          <nxce:simpleAltitude>350</nxce:simpleAltitude>
        </nxce:assignedAltitude>
      </nxcm:reportedAltitude>
      <nxcm:position>
        <nxce:latitude>
          <nxce:latitudeDMS degrees="45" minutes="40" direction="NORTH"/>
        </nxce:latitude>
        <nxce:longitude>
          <nxce:longitudeDMS degrees="056" minutes="58" direction="WEST"/>
        </nxce:longitude>
      </nxcm:position>
   </trackInformation>
  </asdiMessage>
  <asdiMessage sourceFacility="CCM" sourceTimeStamp="2015-03-15T23:57:27Z" trigger="TZ">
    <trackposition>
      <nxcm:aircraftId>UAL936</nxcm:aircraftId>
      <nxcm:speed>470</nxcm:speed>
      <nxcm:reportedAltitude>
        <nxce:assignedAltitude>
          <nxce:simpleAltitude>350</nxce:simpleAltitude>
        </nxce:assignedAltitude>
     </nxcm:reportedAltitude>
      <nxcm:position>
        <nxce:latitude>
          <nxce:latitudeDMS degrees="44" minutes="43" direction="NORTH"/>
        </nxce:latitude>
        <nxce:longitude>
          <nxce:longitudeDMS degrees="062" minutes="42" direction="WEST"/>
        </nxce:longitude>
      </nxcm:position>
    </trackposition>
  </asdiMessage>
</asdiOutput>
```

I want to extract the values 
`sourceFacility="CCZM"`,  `sourceTimeStamp="2011-03-15T23:57:27Z"`, and `trigger="TZ"`

But the XPath should not return the values for `asdiMessage` which has a child element called `trackposition`.
So the following value should not be returned:
`asdiMessage sourceFacility="CCM" sourceTimeStamp="2015-03-15T23:57:27Z" trigger="TZ"` because the child element.

I tried this `/asdiOutput/asdiMessage[not(contains(trackposition))]` but this doesn't return anything at all

Comment: Is there any thing you tried up to now?. You know about default namespaces and know how to handel same in your programming languages?

Comment: Apologies HR i updated my question with my try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the typo in the end tag of the root element:

`</asdiOuput>` should be `</asdiOutput>`

Next, make sure you have defined a namespace prefix for `http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS`:

```
xis="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS"
```

Then, this XPath,

```
/xis:asdiOutput/xis:asdiMessage[not(xis:trackposition)]/@sourceFacility
```

will select `"CCZM"` as requested.

You can construct XPaths for `sourceTimeStamp` and `trigger` similarly.

Comment: Hi kjhughes how did you figure out from the xml that asdiOutput is in the namespace that you equated to xis

Comment: On the root element, there is a default namespace declaration: `xmlns="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS"`

Comment: Thanks for the help i was just wondering how did you get this answer so fast my Notepad++ xpath  is crap is there a online tool that can help me with getting a xpath ?

Comment: Fast comes more from nearly two decades of XPath experience than tools, but here's an online XPath tester you might like: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Comment: Pretty Good answer mate.So to be fast with xpath i just need to wait a little over 20 years lol :).

Comment: XPath learning resources: The original [**XPath Recommendation**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is remarkably readable; don't miss the [**location path examples**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#location-paths).  For a deeper treatise, see Michael Kay's [*XSLT 2.0 Programmer's Reference*](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/XSLT-2-0-and-XPath-2-0-Programmer-s-Reference-4th-Edition.productCd-0470192747.html) book, which covers XPath in addition to XSLT.